# What is the Flag 0x40028?

Tags: java, android

In the code below, what is the 0x40028 (262184) Flag? I could not find it anywhere in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAGS_CHANGED), I have even looked for it in various API Level documentation and could not find it.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new 
    android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams(0, 0, 0, 0, 2003, 0x40028, -3);
```

Comment: i m not sure but i think its about the windows dimension changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a combination of `WindowManager's` `FLAG_*` constants. As you can see from the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/WindowManager.java), `WindowManager.flags` is compared exclusively to these constants.

`0x40028 == FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`

Perhaps the documentation could be a little better.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you know that it was this specific combination that made up that value? Or are you just using them as an example?

Comment: The constant values are described in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams), and I looked up the values that lined up with the 3 bits that were set. See [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON):

this value `0x40028` is combined by some of the values of these constants:

```
FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
FLAG_TOUCHABLE_WHEN_WAKING
FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
FLAG_FULLSCREEN
FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN
FLAG_SECURE
FLAG_SCALED
FLAG_IGNORE_CHEEK_PRESSES
FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR
FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER
FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH
FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE
FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
```

each of the above flags describes a window behavior and by combining 2 or more of these values by using `|` (bitwise OR operator) you can produce values like `0x40028`.